# Flutter: does pushReplacement delete the stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I call Navigator.push multiple times before Navigator.pushReplacement will Navigator.pushReplacement delete the whole stack or does it only replace the current screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html) only the current route is replaced. The new route and the route below the removed route are notified, and any observers.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't sure If I have understood it correctly.